# How Visual Studio is used for?

Tags: visual-studio

I am totally new in Visual Studio (VS). I just started a new job in the BI team and they works with Visual studio, which is completely new for me. I searched VS in google; however I still have not got a clearly idea how it works.

Is there someone that could explain me what does VS is used for?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Visual Studio is an integrated development environment from Microsoft. It is used to develop computer programs, as well as websites, web apps, web services and mobile apps.for more information please visit here [Micrsooft Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) thanks

Answer (score -1):

For BI job, you can use VS to writing SQL and control DB, VS is more than C++/C#/VB IDE than you think.

Comment: hey Jacky...So far I understood the used it to collaborative work. When you said I can write SQL into VS, it means if I create a new table there, it would be reflect in the DB in Sql server management system (SSMS)?

Comment: Yes, may be you should try it, check the side bar in VS , you may find a tab  called like  "Server Explorer".

Comment: Ok. and do you know that is the advantage of having in VS all SSIS packages? Thanks

Comment: I know nothing about SSIS, I've never  done the BI job before, you should dig in for yourself.